# VB.NET GetProcessesByName method is missing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm building a program in VB whose purpose is to run in the background and automatically update other programs I've created. To do this, it has to check if those programs are still running and, if they are, wait for them to close.

Unfortunately, the program won't compile. The exception states: *GetProcessesByName is not a member of String.* (The *string* it refers to is the `Process` parameter shown in the code below.)

I can't understand why this is happening, because this method has always worked without problems. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. For your reference, here's the code block:

```
Private Function CheckIfRunning(Process As String) As Boolean
    Dim MyProcess() As Process

    MyProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")
    If MyProcess.Count > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a static method on the `Process` class?  Try renaming the function parameter to something else..

Comment: This was the problem. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")

Since you've declared `Process` as a string parameter, `Process.GetProcessesByName` refers to the string instead of the System.Diagnostics method. Alternatively, you can use a different name for the string parameter.

Comment: That's bizarre. I never would've tried something so simple. I assumed by importing System.Diagnostics I wouldn't have to specify in-line. I'm an idiot